# mysql - where multiple column data

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

I have a table with below structure

```
prod_ID | barcode_int | value1  |  value2 | value3
```

sample data set would be

```
156123 | 1 | stock | 2014-03-21 | warehouse1
156123 | 2 | stock | 2014-03-22 | warehouse2
156123 | 3 | return | 2014-03-23 | warehouse1
```

i have physical products with barcodes on them - my barcodes are 12char in length and is composed of joining prod_id and barcode_int values in the following structure:

```
prodid 156123 and barcode_int 1 would produce 001561230001
```

so the first `8 char` is prodid with 0s in the beginning to makeup to `8 digits`
`last 4 char` is barcode_int with 0s in the begining to make up to `4 digits`
in total i have a barcode with `12 digits`

I would like to return the rows from this table with a where clause where I indicate the barcodes I have and in result get the corresponding row data such as

```
select * from products where barcode IN (xxxx,yyyy,zzzz);
```

I can only select on this table.

thanks!

Comment: posible output expected ?

Comment: if I am searching for 001561230001, I need to get 156123 | 1 | stock | 2014-03-21 | warehouse1 , If I have multiple barcodes in my where IN I need to get all corresponding rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
WHERE CONCAT(LPAD(prod_ID, 8, '0'), LPAD(barcoder_int, 4, '0')) IN (xxxx,yyyy,zzzz);
```

Comment: of course you need to use your actual field names and assuming you build your search criteria as necessary. The point in my answer is left padding a field value with LPAD and also using CONCAT function.

Comment: absolutely - I am sure I can play around and build on this one. this works like a charm